# Go to Nth character in the file?

Tags: cursor-movement

`:goto` goes to Nth *byte* of the file. I am looking for a way to go to Nth *character*. Given that Vim supports all kinds of multi-byte encodings, it would be odd if it did not exist, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Excluding newlines

There is a command for go to next character, it is `<space>`.  I assume the option `whichwrap` is default of `b,s` so that space wraps to the next line, and `conceallevel` is 0 so no chars are skipped.  Then to go to the 1723rd character in the file, use

```
:normal! 0go1722 "
```

`"` simply emphasizes the trailing space.  We can make a command wrapper as follows:

```
:command! -nargs=1 GoToChar execute 'normal! 0go' . (<args>-1) . ' '
```

Use like `:GoToChar 1723`

#### Including newlines

An alternative is to use a pattern which consumes characters from the start of the file

```
/\%^\_.\{1723}/e
```

In this case, end-of-line is counted.

Comment: Make sure you disable concealing here. An alternative might be to use `/\%^\_.\{1723}/e`